# Mitigate user removing required field from form

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a few forms for signing in/up or continuing as guest using the firebase. I want the user to be forced to put in an email so I can identify the user when they come to pick up their order and send them a receipt after they've paid. There is nothing preventing the user from just inspecting element and removing the required field, and the firebase functions are called from the front end so I cant even use my server to double check there is an email.

Is there a way to mitigate this? Aside from Firebase specific solutions, is there a way to mitigate this issue with all required fields? There is obviously a way as other websites implement this but I'm not sure how

Maybe run a script to check if the required attribute has been removed but that too can be deleted or edited.

Comment: Any reason you could not do client-side validation using JavaScript?

Comment: The client-side validation works fine. But specifically for anonymous sign on for example, the function doesn't require an email or name. I want to require those things so I can identify the person, and send them a receipt once they pay and checkout. If I put the require attribute on the email/name fields for my anonymous sign on form, I am able to just inspect element and remove the required field. The anonymous sign on function will still fire with no errors because it only requires a FirebaseAuth object as a parameter.

Comment: I just realized that you probably mean why not run a script to check if the required attribute has been removed, my assumption was this can also be modified no? and along with that I'm not entirely sure what's the proper way to do that for a required form fields. Do I just check if there's an email before I run my anonymous sign on function? That did cross my mind but it seemed too simple lol. Pretty easy to delete that too no? i could just be over thinking it

Comment: If you're calling the Firebase functions from the front-end, then there's nothing you can do at all to prevent users entering whatever they like. Users can decompile your app, pull out the code that interfaces with Firebase and just call it directly. I have to admit I've never worked with Firebase before, but I hope that you don't have any secrets for accessing Firebase in your front-end.

Comment: I made sure anything that was secretive went through my server first. This is the only part I’m a bit stuck on. It’s nothing concerning security thankfully, just need to be able to identify whoever is ordering. Iv seen stripe implement something similar to what I want. if I for example take away the require attribute from the credit card section of their payment form, something adds on error attributes that prevent submission without everything filled out.

Comment: I was actually referring to something like what Raheut Rahwana has suggested below.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the field in question exists and has a value.

```js
const form = document.forms.form;

form.onsubmit = () => {
  event.preventDefault();
  signInAnonymously(event.currentTarget.elements.email);
};

function signInAnonymously(email) {
  if (email && email.value) {
    console.log("Authenticate with Firebase anonymously");
  } else {
    console.log("Email is required")
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="form">
<label>
  <b>Email:</b>
  <input name="email" type="email" required>
</label>
<button>Sign In Anonymously</button>
</form>
```